# How to pass request value through request body in rest web service

Tags: .net, web-services

I am creating simple demo rest web service in .net,there are two ways to send data in web service

```
Through Query String
Through Request Body
```

I have written the following code and I able to consume web service through Query string

```
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
    UriTemplate = "xml?id={id}")]
    string XMLData(string id);

    public string XMLData(string id)
    {
          return "You  request id is  " + id ;
    }
```

But I have to pass the ID value through request body and not through query string .How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use the Form Body, then you have to add a parameter to your method :

```
string XMLData(string id, data As IO.Stream);
```

Then in the method, you can access the body of the Post by :

```
 Dim strData As String = New IO.StreamReader(data).ReadToEnd()
```